# keypress event is not getting fired when i press enter key

Tags: jquery, textbox, keypress, enter

I have attached a keypress event to my textbox. when the user presses other keys i am doing some processing work, but when the user presses the Enter key i am submitting the value in the textbox to some server. I am able to do all processing and every thing is fine, but when i press enter key the event is not getting fired. so, i ma unable to submit my value to the server.

Here is my code:

```
$("#txt" + filterID).keypress(txtInput_keypress);

function txtInput_keypress(e) { 
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    var strValue = $(this).val()+ String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var bool = $.trim(strValue).match(reg); 
    if (code == 13) {  
        //textbox value submission code
    }
    else if (parseFloat($.trim(strValue)) > max) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (bool) {  
        return true;
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }  
}
```

whats wrong with my code? Please somebody help me to fix this issue.

Comment: You're not passing on the event, or the (e) in your function!

Comment: @adeneo - jQuery does that when it calls the function.

Comment: @nnnnnn - You're right, was'nt thinking, tried testing this, but seems the variable reg is not defined, maybe that's the problem, seems to work just fine without the `var bool = ...` line.

Comment: @adeno, reg is a regular expression we have used to validate the string. I am not supposed post that here.

Comment: @Dinesh - Did you check firebug or chrome's inspector for errors, and is there a preventDefault when enter is pressed as well?

Comment: There has to be a bug somewhere, if no errors are reported, start commenting out lines until it's working, then comment them back in one by one until you find what's causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, without more code this can't be answered. What you posted works fine. Something else is causing it to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var filterID = 1, reg = '^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$', max = 1000;

            $("#txt" + filterID).keypress(txtInput_keypress);

            function txtInput_keypress(e) {
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                var strValue = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                var bool = $.trim(strValue).match(reg);
                if (code == 13) {
                    //textbox value submission code
                    //$('form#test').submit(); // if alert is not coming uncoment this line.
                }
                else if (parseFloat($.trim(strValue)) > max) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else if (bool) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });                
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="test" action="javascript:alert('success!');">
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: filterId, reg, max variables are missing.